# error in the row number of data frame records and so that record is ignored in calculations

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that does some calculations and calculates an object f.con. the problem is that when i print aux1 the row numbers after row 22 are incorrect, it gives row number 221 instead of 23. I do some further calculations and then that row is ignored which is basically a constraint.

```
library(utils); library(xlsx)
library(lpSolve) # load lpSolve package previously installed
library(lpSolveAPI)
datadea<- structure(list(DMUS = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), Input1Cash = c(5, 6, 
 4, 8, 5, 8, 4.4, 2.6, 3.4, 3.6, 2, 3, 3, 2.6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 
 6, 8, 9), Input2LEV = c(4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4.4, 8, 8, 4.4, 7, 
 7, 5.6, 5, 4, 3.2, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 2), Output1EPS = c(1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
 members = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("DMUS", 
 "Input1Cash", "Input2LEV", "Output1EPS", "members"
 ), row.names = c(NA, 22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have the following code that performs some calculations:

```
N <- 22 # number of DMU
s = 2 # number of inputs
m = 1 # number of outputs
inputs = datadea[,c(2,3)]
outputs = datadea[,4]
library(lpSolve) # load lpSolve package previously installed
library(lpSolveAPI)
f.rhs <- c(rep(0,N),1) # RHS constraints
f.dir <- c(rep("<=",N),"=") # directions of the constraints
aux <- cbind(-1*inputs,outputs) # matrix of constraint coefficients in (6)
for (i in 1:N) {
f.obj <- c(rep(0,s),t(datadea[i,4])) # objective function coefficients
f.con <- f.con <- rbind(aux, c(unlist(datadea[i,c(2,3)]), rep(0, m)))

results <- lp("max",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,scale=1,compute.sens=TRUE)
  multipliers <- results$solution # input and output weights
efficiency <- results$objval # efficiency score
duals <- results$duals # shadow prices
if (i==1) {
weights = c(multipliers[seq(1,s+m)])
effcrs <- efficiency
lambdas = duals [seq(1,N)]
} else {
weights <- rbind(weights,c(multipliers[seq(1,s+m)]))
effcrs <- rbind(effcrs , efficiency)
lambdas <- rbind(lambdas,duals[seq(1,N)])
}
}
matrix_results <- cbind(effcrs,weights,lambdas)
rownames(matrix_results) <- rownames(datadea)
colnames(matrix_results) <- c("efficiency",colnames(datadea)[1:(s+m)], 
rownames(datadea))
rownames(matrix_results) <- rownames(datadea)

crosseffmin = matrix(0,nrow=N,ncol=N) # initialize cross efficiency matrix
i=18
totaloutputs <- sum(outputs) ; 
totaloutputs = totaloutputs-as.numeric(outputs[i])
totalinputs <- colSums(inputs) ; 
totalinputs = totalinputs-as.numeric(unlist(inputs[i,])) 
f.obj <- c(totaloutputs,as.numeric(-totalinputs))
aux1 <- cbind(outputs,-1*inputs); aux11 = aux1[which(row(aux1)[,1]!=i),] ;  
aux1<-aux11[1:(N-1),]
aux1<- rbind(aux1,c(0*rep(1,m),as.numeric(inputs[i,])))
aux1<- rbind(aux1,c(as.numeric(outputs[i]),
effcrs[i]*as.numeric(-inputs[i,])))
f.con <- aux1 
print(aux1)
```

In the resulting data frame aux1, you can see the ambiguous row number after row 22. you may check in the following output:

```
aux1
    outputs Input1Cash Input2LEV
1         1       -5.0      -4.0
2         1       -6.0      -5.0
3         1       -4.0      -5.0
4         1       -8.0      -5.0
5         1       -5.0      -6.0
6         1       -8.0      -3.0
7         1       -4.4      -4.4
8         1       -2.6      -8.0
9         1       -3.4      -8.0
10        1       -3.6      -4.4
11        1       -2.0      -7.0
12        1       -3.0      -7.0
13        1       -3.0      -5.6
14        1       -2.6      -5.0
15        1       -4.0      -4.0
16        1       -5.0      -3.2
17        1       -6.0      -4.0
19        1       -7.0      -3.0
20        1       -6.0      -2.5
21        1       -8.0      -2.0
22        1       -9.0      -2.0
221       0        4.0       3.5
23        1       -4.0      -3.5
```

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @ycw It didn't work as if you read the last two lines in the code, I am basically passing an object aux1 to f.con. so you need to check aux1.

Comment: What did you mean? I did not change any of your post. All I did is add a `dataframe` tag so others can find your post easier.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your analysis, but it seems like you are using `rbind` to combine your data. If the row name is not what you expected, you can do the following after the `aux1<- rbind(aux1,c(0*rep(1,m),as.numeric(inputs[i,])))` line.

```
rownames(aux1) <- 1:nrow(aux1)
```

This will make sure the row name is the same as the row number.

Comment: Or assign it to NULL i.e `rownames(aux1) <- NULL`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in you omitting the 18th line and then adding another 22nd line. When you omit the 18th line in the data.frame the row.names are not made new but they are the same. So 18 is missing but 22 is still there. You can easily solve this by writing the following:

```
# .... your code here ...
f.obj <- c(totaloutputs,as.numeric(-totalinputs))
aux1 <- cbind(outputs,-1*inputs); aux11 = aux1[which(row(aux1)[,1]!=i),] ;  
aux1<-aux11[1:(N-1),]
row.names(aux1) <- 1:nrow(aux1) # this is the new line
aux1<- rbind(aux1,c(0*rep(1,m),as.numeric(inputs[i,])))
aux1<- rbind(aux1,c(as.numeric(outputs[i]),
                    effcrs[i]*as.numeric(-inputs[i,])))
f.con <- aux1 
print(aux1)
```

the line which starts with row.names is the new one. Just embed this into your current code and evreything will work fine! It just rewrites the row.names so you can safely add a 22nd row.